# Part Number and Sku has to be hidden from all user's view

Tags: bigcommerce

Full Part Number and  SKU ID should be added for Internal reference purpose and has to be hidden from all user's view.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You will need to use CSS to hide those items

Answer (score 0):

You can remove SKU from store setting. Also check below screenshot for your reference. This is a great option for non developers. Go to admin > Store Setup > Store Settings > Display > scroll down to product settings.

[image: screenshot]

As for the part number, which Bigcommerce product field are you using to hold the part number value? Is it the UPC field? Or something else?